# How to capture the data from yahoo finance streaming?

Tags: c#, java, html, ajax, tcp

Yahoo finance streaming uses a method of a file constantly increasing in size to update their data:

http://uk.finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^FTSE

Is there anyway I could collect this data (i'm not going to sell it- wanted to make my own amateur trade screen)?

Comment: Why is this tagged with c# _and_ java? And why ajax _and_ tcp?

Comment: Writing in Java or C#, answer could be related to HTML, Ajax or TCP???

Comment: Did you check YQL community tables? I am sure there must be something related to this. It will let you write SQL like query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse HTML, I would recommend [Apache Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html). But you better find a RSS/JSON/XML stream.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

You could get the HTML and parse out what you want. Here is some basic code using the Apache client:

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.*;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.*;

public class YahooFinanceScraper {

// HTTP GET the given URL
private static String HttpGET(String url) {

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(url);

    int responseCode = 0;
    String responseHTML = null;

    try {
        responseCode = client.executeMethod(method);
        responseHTML = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log me!
    } finally {
        method.releaseConnection();
    }

    return response;
}

String quote(String symbol) {
    String data = "";
    String HTML = HttpGET(YAHOO_FINANCE_QUOTE_URL + symbol);

    // BIG TODO: parse the HTML for whatever data you find interesting

    return data;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    YahooFinanceScraper y = new YahooFinanceScraper();
    String data = y.quote("FTSE");
}

static final String YAHOO_FINANCE_QUOTE_URL = "http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^";
}
```